Can I get all asterisks on the first playthrough in Bravely Second?
I just started and I hit a point in the game where I had to choose between one side or another and it gave a warning about not being able to access on asterisk.
From my experience with Bravely Default I know there's a New Game plus, so I am guessing that's one way to get all the asterisks assuming the current ones carry over.

Yes in you can carry over the asterisks even the Level of them.

Yes, you can get all asterisks in one playthrough of the game. Any asterisks not obtained during "one or the other" choices can be obtained later in the game, so you would just have to wait until later to obtain them.
I played through the game only once (no new game+) and obtained all asterisks. There are also some Reddit threads that support this. The least spoiler-y one i found, bases on the top few answers, can be found here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/bravelydefault/comments/49uq43/bravely_second_is_it_possible_to_obtain_all_jobs/
